# Clothes to pack for June in Geneve?

Tags: switzerland, weather-and-climate, geneva

Going to Geneve for the month of June.  Planning on some light excursions nearby (within 70km) and maybe some light hiking, possibly along the Aravis Range.

Should I bother bringing shorts?  Do I need a heavy coat?  Should I have boots for snow at 2500m or so, or will it be gone by June?

Comment: I was going to write an answer ut no longer have time: zip-off hiking trousers are ideal.  Carry a fleece and waterproof, and dont forget sunscreen if you're in the mountains

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was in Geneva last June and the weather was pretty varied. The pattern tended to be cooler in the mornings, baking hot by midday and a nice mild temperature on an evening with warm showers appearing from nowhere anywhere in between!

My go to for these sort of trips is usually shorts, jeans, a jumper/hooded jacket and a light weatherproof jacket. Layers are key!

Comment: I agree but now I found hiking trousers I do not use jeans for traveling anymore. Jeans stay wet much longer, are not warm enough in cold windy weather and are hot when the temperature goes up.

Comment: These are the things I packed, and it is turning out to be just right.  Some mornings are pretty chilly, and some days are quite hot.  We went to chamonix for a day trip and hiked to 2500m in a t-shirt.  Walked over some melting piles of snow in our sandals.  :)  My gf brought a very heavy jacket and it will definitely go unused.

Answer (score 4):

You have two options, go with the averages over several or even many years or look at a weather forecast about 10 days before you leave and keep looking once a day or once every few days to see the predictions develop.

I would personally go with the second and use your own home situation to base your plans on.

It always pays to bring shorts and rain gear, as rare hotter and wetter days are always possible.
And keep a very good eye on the snow line. If the weather turns bad that line can come down the mountains rather fast.

Comment: Mountain weather is notoriously unpredictable, and the current climate crisis is making historical data less than useful.  Being prepared for both weather extremes is always a good idea, even though Swiss mountains are much more hospitable than most

Comment: And by all means, if you intend to hike up to 2500m you need good shoes anyway. Most hiking shoes should be good enough to let you traverse the the inevitable leftover bands of snow.